# Having Column as Column Sum or Difference others with Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a hibernate pojo class and it has some field. Assume that there are three field. One is sum of the others. I means there are column 1, column 2 , column 3.

How can i define column 3 =column1+column2 with Hibernate as annotation.
I guess we can define it with standart SQL  like

create table x( columnt1 ......, column2 ......, column3 as column1+column2)

i'm not sure , is there a way to do that with hibernate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leave out the column and use properties

```
public int getProperty3()
{
    return getProperty1() + getProperty2();
}
```